# How to merge two element inside a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
[[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033], [11710000099]]
```

I'd like to merge all the sublist of length 1 with one of the other (it doesn't matter which one).

So, for example, I would like to obtain:

```
[[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033, 11710000099]]
```

or

```
[[11710000035, 11710000034, 11710000099], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033]]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain the context? The requirement is quite vague. Why not, for example, simply flatten it to `[11710000035, 11710000034, 11710000099, 11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033]`?

Comment: Because I just need to merge the 1-length elements, I want to keep invariant the other elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in 2 steps.

First, collect all the items in the list with more than one element.

```
l = [[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033], [11710000099]]
r = [i for i in l if len(i) > 1]
```

Then add the single elements in one of the items of `r`. Since it doesn't matter for you, I would simply add them to the first item in the list.

```
for i in l:
    if len(i) == 1:
        r[0] += i

print(r)
[[11710000035, 11710000034, 11710000099], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward, not so elegant, potential solution:

```
l = [[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033], [11710000099]]
j = 0
for i, e in enumerate(l):
   if len(e) > 1:
     j = i
   if len(e) == 1:
     l[j] = l[j] + e
     del l[i]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be deleting 1 length elements from list and adding another list and appending those elements to our list's first element.

```
a = [[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038,
                                  11710000031, 11710000033], [11710000099]]
x = []
for ind, item in enumerate(a):
    if (len(item) == 1):
        x.append(a[ind][0])
        del a[ind]

if a:
    a[0].extend(x)

print(a)
```

Comment: I'd like to append the 1-length element just as number, not as a list of 1 element

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

A variant using chain:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033], [11710000099]]

big_lists = [i for i in l if len(i) > 1 ]
big_lists[0] += chain.from_iterable( i for i in l if len(i) == 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. Care about length of data. If data length is less than 2 it throws an error

```py
data = [[11710000035, 11710000034], [11710000038, 11710000031, 11710000033], [11710000099]]

for idx, sub_list in enumerate(data):
  if(len(sub_list)==1):
    if(idx!=0):
      data[idx-1] += data.pop(idx)
    else:
      data[idx+1] += data.pop(idx)

print(data)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can merge a list with +.

In your case:

```
result_list = [your_list[0]]
result_list.append(your_list[1] + your_list[2])
```

Comment: he needs to merge the list which is having only 1 element.